# How do I change the letter space on the wordpress menu in the backend section?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, elementor

I wanted to ask if you can help me to fix the following design issue on the top of the WordPress backend menu: As you can see on the screenshot in the marked areas the space between the letters is too large. How can edit this?

Thank you for your help

I have tried to zoom the screen and to find these settings in the elementor menu, but it didn't work.